# C# drawing with a restriction

Tags: c#, drawing

I'm working with a project that gets information out of a DXF file(a drawing file from autocad or any other drawing program). I get information from it and it shows the borders of a panel. In this panel I need to set lines, but when there are lines with coordinates OUTSIDE the panel I'm not allowed to draw them.

Below you can find an image, maybe it makes a bit more clear.

So the white lines are bricks and they need glue lines(yellow), The aquamarine line is the contour line. Outside this line it is not allowed to draw Glue lines(the yellow lines)

As you can see on brick with NR 4BA87 it draws glue lines outside the panel.

[image: Example of drawlines]

I need some sort of check if a `point` is inside my contour/panel I can draw it else don't draw it. How can I do this?

***edit:***

I draw these lines from a list so it would be great if I could remove(or not add them) the gluelines from my list that are outside my panel.

I've got a list with Points that are the contourpoints:

```
public List<PointF> ListContourPoints = new List<PointF>();
```

And I've got a list with glue lines:

```
List<GlueLine> glueLines = new List<GlueLine>();
```

my `GlueLine` class has 2 `PointF`in it, `StartPosition` and `EndPosition`.

It would be nice if I get something like:

```
if(GlueLines.StartPosition is INSIDE panel && GlueLines.EndPosition is INSIDE panel)
{
    glueLines.Add(gl);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms? If so, just set the [`Graphics.Clip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) region before doing any painting. (There's an equivalent method for WPF graphics.)

Comment: But the bricks need to be drawn, even if its outside the panel, So I can't block all the drawing

Comment: So just set the clip region only when drawing the elements that need to be clipped, and restore it afterwards.

Comment: Well tahts maybe an option, but I actually need to remove them from my list, I also use this list to set these lines back in a DXF file, sorry for not metioning that.

Comment: I'm assuming you know where the panel edges are? As in positions?

Comment: I only have the positions of each corner in points.

Comment: Then you can find out the rectangular shapes that these create, once you have these just do a positional checking

Comment: And can you make a small example? So I get little push in the right direction? Since I don't know how to check if a Point is in the rectangular shape.

Comment: Will the panel always be of similar shapes?

Answer (score 0):

You have got the positional data of all the `Points` that make up the corners of the panel. So all you need to do is find out the rectangular shapes that make up the panel and then do positional checking on the lines.

An example function to create the rectangles would look something like the below, Note however that this function is created under the assumption that the panel is in the same shape as the example one provided, some more logic will be needed to create one which encompasses all of the variations:

```
private static Rectangle[] SplitPointsIntoRectangles(Point[] pa)
{
    pa = pa.OrderBy(p => p.X).ToArray();
    Point[] leftmost = pa.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.X == pa[0].X).ToArray();
    Point[] rightmost = pa.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.X == pa[pa.Length - 1].X).ToArray();

    pa = pa.OrderBy(p => p.Y).ToArray();
    Point[] topmost = pa.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.Y == pa[0].Y).ToArray();
    Point[] bottommost = pa.Select(p => p).Where(p => p.Y == pa[pa.Length - 1].Y).ToArray();

    List<Point> edges = new List<Point>();
    edges.AddRange(leftmost);
    edges.AddRange(rightmost);
    edges.AddRange(topmost);
    edges.AddRange(bottommost);

    Point middlePixel = pa.FirstOrDefault(p => !edges.Contains(p));

    Rectangle[] ra = new Rectangle[2];
    ra[0] = new Rectangle(leftmost[0].X, leftmost.Min(p => p.Y), rightmost[0].X - leftmost[0].X, bottommost[0].Y - leftmost[0].Y);
    ra[1] = new Rectangle(topmost.Min(p => p.X), topmost[0].Y, rightmost[0].X - middlePixel.X, middlePixel.Y - topmost[0].Y);

    return ra;
}
```

Once we have the rectangles we then need to make sure the lines are not outside of them, for this we can use the [Rectangle.Intersects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0(v=vs.110).aspx) method. For this we use the points of each of the glue lines to create a rectangle, like so (assuming all these lines are horizontal):

```
Rectangle glueLineRect = new Rectangle(glueLineStartPoint.X, glueLineStartPoint.Y, glueLineEndPosition.X - glueLineStartPoint.X, 1);
```

If the following function returns an empty rectangle then the two rectangles do not intersect, else they do. Note: this function will return a none empty rectangle if the rectangles partially intersect.

```
Rectangle intersectionRect = Rectangle.Intersect(MainRect, glueLineRect);
```

This can then be extended to test on all of the rectangles contained within the panel and if it fails on all of them then the glue line resides outside of the panel.

I created this answer to get you started, the `SplitPointsIntoRectangles` method needs to be made generic. Also the looping needs to created to test whether the Glue Lines reside inside of the panel or not.

Comment: When I use ur code, `RectangleF intersectionRect2 = RectangleF.Intersect(a_ContourRects[1], glueLineRect);` returns an rectangle with everything on `0`. Still thanks for the help I can figure some stuff out now by myself

Comment: @Bart if it returns an empty rectangle that means that the rectangles do not intersect

Comment: @Bart If this helped you feel free to upvote and/or mark it as the answer so future visitors can see